# Change PID for FTDI for FTDI X Series

Tags: c++, ftdi

The default PID for FTDI X series chip is 0X6015. I used to use FT_EE_Program to the PID for old chip 0X6001. It worked well. 
However, this function does not work for the new chip. I am using the function FT_EEPROM_Program to change the PID for 0X6015. The following is my code:

```
 int CUsbPort::WriteEEprom_X()
 {
      FT_STATUS status;
      m_x_series.common.VendorId = m_ftData.VendorId;                 // 0x0403
      m_x_series.common.ProductId = m_ftData.ProductId;             // 0x6015
      status = FT_EEPROM_Program(m_hComm,&m_x_series, sizeof(ft_eeprom_x_series),
      m_ManufacturerBuf, m_ManufacturerIdBuf, m_DescriptionBuf, m_SerialNumberBuf);
      if( status != FT_OK )
        return -1;
      return 1;
  }
```

However, the return value for status is FT_INVALID_PARAMETER. Please provide suggestions on how to change the PID. I was able to change the PID using FTDI utility FT_Prog. I did not find an example for using FT_EEPROM_Program.

Comment: the first question that comes to mind is, why would you want to change the PID in the first place? But aside from that, maybe FT_EEPROM_Program does not support your chip.

Answer (score 0):

The  D2XX programmers guide (FT000071), clearly states: "By default, the driver will support a limited set of VID and PID matched devices (VID 0x0403 with PIDs 0x6001, 0x6010, 0x6006 only)" So your device is not supported.

You will find this statement in the remarks section of all methods used by FT_EEPROM_Program.

Answer (score 0):

To program the EEPROM on the chip you need to set all the values within the `m_x_series` structure that you are passing to the `FT_EEPROM_Program`.  From your example code you could be passing uninitialized memory to the program function; the underlying code may be validating what you have sent and rejecting it if the values are not valid.

There is a command line version of FT_Prog that will allow you to program multiple chips quickly.  You need to generate a template file with the new PID using the GUI version of the app and then run the command line version passing in the .xml file you generated.

Answer (score 0):

The following script uses `FT_EE_Read()` and `FT_EE_Program()`.
`FT_EE_Read()` does not set `Signature1`, `Signature2` and `Version`.
So these need to be set before `FT_EE_Program()`,
then there is no `FT_INVALID_PARAMETER` any more.

```
#python
from cffi import FFI
class FTDIData:
   """ read and write to FTDI chip
   >>> ftdid = FTDIData()
   >>> ftdid.VendorId = 0x1111
   >>> ftdid.ProductId = 0x2222
   >>> ftdid.Manufacturer = "XYZ"
   >>> ftdid.ManufacturerId = "MI"
   >>> ftdid.Description = "Desc"
   >>> ftdid.SerialNumber = "SE000"
   >>> ftdid.program()
   >>> ftdid.close()
   """
   def __init__(self,other=None):
      self.ffi = FFI()
      self.ffi.cdef("""
      typedef struct ft_program_data {
             DWORD Signature1;          // Header - must be 0x00000000 
             DWORD Signature2;          // Header - must be 0xffffffff
             DWORD Version;             // Header - FT_PROGRAM_DATA version
             //         0 = original
             //         1 = FT2232 extensions
             //         2 = FT232R extensions
             //         3 = FT2232H extensions
             //         4 = FT4232H extensions
             //         5 = FT232H extensions
             WORD VendorId;             // 0x0403
             WORD ProductId;                // 0x6001
             char *Manufacturer;            // "FTDI"
             char *ManufacturerId;      // "FT"
             char *Description;         // "USB HS Serial Converter"
             char *SerialNumber;            // "FT000001" if fixed, or NULL
             WORD MaxPower;             // 0 < MaxPower <= 500
             WORD PnP;                  // 0 = disabled, 1 = enabled
             WORD SelfPowered;          // 0 = bus powered, 1 = self powered
             WORD RemoteWakeup;         // 0 = not capable, 1 = capable
             //
             // Rev4 (FT232B) extensions
             //
             UCHAR Rev4;                    // non-zero if Rev4 chip, zero otherwise
             UCHAR IsoIn;               // non-zero if in endpoint is isochronous
             UCHAR IsoOut;              // non-zero if out endpoint is isochronous
             UCHAR PullDownEnable;      // non-zero if pull down enabled
             UCHAR SerNumEnable;            // non-zero if serial number to be used
             UCHAR USBVersionEnable;        // non-zero if chip uses USBVersion
             WORD USBVersion;           // BCD (0x0200 => USB2)
             //
             // Rev 5 (FT2232) extensions
             //
             UCHAR Rev5;                    // non-zero if Rev5 chip, zero otherwise
             UCHAR IsoInA;              // non-zero if in endpoint is isochronous
             UCHAR IsoInB;              // non-zero if in endpoint is isochronous
             UCHAR IsoOutA;             // non-zero if out endpoint is isochronous
             UCHAR IsoOutB;             // non-zero if out endpoint is isochronous
             UCHAR PullDownEnable5;     // non-zero if pull down enabled
             UCHAR SerNumEnable5;       // non-zero if serial number to be used
             UCHAR USBVersionEnable5;   // non-zero if chip uses USBVersion
             WORD USBVersion5;          // BCD (0x0200 => USB2)
             UCHAR AIsHighCurrent;      // non-zero if interface is high current
             UCHAR BIsHighCurrent;      // non-zero if interface is high current
             UCHAR IFAIsFifo;           // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO
             UCHAR IFAIsFifoTar;            // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO CPU target
             UCHAR IFAIsFastSer;            // non-zero if interface is Fast serial
             UCHAR AIsVCP;              // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
             UCHAR IFBIsFifo;           // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO
             UCHAR IFBIsFifoTar;            // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO CPU target
             UCHAR IFBIsFastSer;            // non-zero if interface is Fast serial
             UCHAR BIsVCP;              // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
             //
             // Rev 6 (FT232R) extensions
             //
             UCHAR UseExtOsc;           // Use External Oscillator
             UCHAR HighDriveIOs;            // High Drive I/Os
             UCHAR EndpointSize;            // Endpoint size
             UCHAR PullDownEnableR;     // non-zero if pull down enabled
             UCHAR SerNumEnableR;       // non-zero if serial number to be used
             UCHAR InvertTXD;           // non-zero if invert TXD
             UCHAR InvertRXD;           // non-zero if invert RXD
             UCHAR InvertRTS;           // non-zero if invert RTS
             UCHAR InvertCTS;           // non-zero if invert CTS
             UCHAR InvertDTR;           // non-zero if invert DTR
             UCHAR InvertDSR;           // non-zero if invert DSR
             UCHAR InvertDCD;           // non-zero if invert DCD
             UCHAR InvertRI;                // non-zero if invert RI
             UCHAR Cbus0;               // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus1;               // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus2;               // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus3;               // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus4;               // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR RIsD2XX;             // non-zero if using D2XX driver
             //
             // Rev 7 (FT2232H) Extensions
             //
             UCHAR PullDownEnable7;     // non-zero if pull down enabled
             UCHAR SerNumEnable7;       // non-zero if serial number to be used
             UCHAR ALSlowSlew;          // non-zero if AL pins have slow slew
             UCHAR ALSchmittInput;      // non-zero if AL pins are Schmitt input
             UCHAR ALDriveCurrent;      // valid values are 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA
             UCHAR AHSlowSlew;          // non-zero if AH pins have slow slew
             UCHAR AHSchmittInput;      // non-zero if AH pins are Schmitt input
             UCHAR AHDriveCurrent;      // valid values are 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA
             UCHAR BLSlowSlew;          // non-zero if BL pins have slow slew
             UCHAR BLSchmittInput;      // non-zero if BL pins are Schmitt input
             UCHAR BLDriveCurrent;      // valid values are 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA
             UCHAR BHSlowSlew;          // non-zero if BH pins have slow slew
             UCHAR BHSchmittInput;      // non-zero if BH pins are Schmitt input
             UCHAR BHDriveCurrent;      // valid values are 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA
             UCHAR IFAIsFifo7;          // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO
             UCHAR IFAIsFifoTar7;       // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO CPU target
             UCHAR IFAIsFastSer7;       // non-zero if interface is Fast serial
             UCHAR AIsVCP7;             // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
             UCHAR IFBIsFifo7;          // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO
             UCHAR IFBIsFifoTar7;       // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO CPU target
             UCHAR IFBIsFastSer7;       // non-zero if interface is Fast serial
             UCHAR BIsVCP7;             // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
             UCHAR PowerSaveEnable;     // non-zero if using BCBUS7 to save power for self-powered designs
             //
             // Rev 8 (FT4232H) Extensions
             //
             UCHAR PullDownEnable8;     // non-zero if pull down enabled
             UCHAR SerNumEnable8;       // non-zero if serial number to be used
             UCHAR ASlowSlew;           // non-zero if A pins have slow slew
             UCHAR ASchmittInput;       // non-zero if A pins are Schmitt input
             UCHAR ADriveCurrent;       // valid values are 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA
             UCHAR BSlowSlew;           // non-zero if B pins have slow slew
             UCHAR BSchmittInput;       // non-zero if B pins are Schmitt input
             UCHAR BDriveCurrent;       // valid values are 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA
             UCHAR CSlowSlew;           // non-zero if C pins have slow slew
             UCHAR CSchmittInput;       // non-zero if C pins are Schmitt input
             UCHAR CDriveCurrent;       // valid values are 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA
             UCHAR DSlowSlew;           // non-zero if D pins have slow slew
             UCHAR DSchmittInput;       // non-zero if D pins are Schmitt input
             UCHAR DDriveCurrent;       // valid values are 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA
             UCHAR ARIIsTXDEN;          // non-zero if port A uses RI as RS485 TXDEN
             UCHAR BRIIsTXDEN;          // non-zero if port B uses RI as RS485 TXDEN
             UCHAR CRIIsTXDEN;          // non-zero if port C uses RI as RS485 TXDEN
             UCHAR DRIIsTXDEN;          // non-zero if port D uses RI as RS485 TXDEN
             UCHAR AIsVCP8;             // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
             UCHAR BIsVCP8;             // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
             UCHAR CIsVCP8;             // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
             UCHAR DIsVCP8;             // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
             //
             // Rev 9 (FT232H) Extensions
             //
             UCHAR PullDownEnableH;     // non-zero if pull down enabled
             UCHAR SerNumEnableH;       // non-zero if serial number to be used
             UCHAR ACSlowSlewH;         // non-zero if AC pins have slow slew
             UCHAR ACSchmittInputH;     // non-zero if AC pins are Schmitt input
             UCHAR ACDriveCurrentH;     // valid values are 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA
             UCHAR ADSlowSlewH;         // non-zero if AD pins have slow slew
             UCHAR ADSchmittInputH;     // non-zero if AD pins are Schmitt input
             UCHAR ADDriveCurrentH;     // valid values are 4mA, 8mA, 12mA, 16mA
             UCHAR Cbus0H;              // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus1H;              // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus2H;              // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus3H;              // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus4H;              // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus5H;              // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus6H;              // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus7H;              // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus8H;              // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR Cbus9H;              // Cbus Mux control
             UCHAR IsFifoH;             // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO
             UCHAR IsFifoTarH;          // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO CPU target
             UCHAR IsFastSerH;          // non-zero if interface is Fast serial
             UCHAR IsFT1248H;           // non-zero if interface is FT1248
             UCHAR FT1248CpolH;         // FT1248 clock polarity - clock idle high (1) or clock idle low (0)
             UCHAR FT1248LsbH;          // FT1248 data is LSB (1) or MSB (0)
             UCHAR FT1248FlowControlH;  // FT1248 flow control enable
             UCHAR IsVCPH;              // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
             UCHAR PowerSaveEnableH;        // non-zero if using ACBUS7 to save power for self-powered designs

      } FT_PROGRAM_DATA, *PFT_PROGRAM_DATA;
      ULONG FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(
          ULONG *lpdwNumDevs
          );
      ULONG FT_Open(
          int deviceNumber,
          PVOID *pHandle
          );
      ULONG FT_Close(
          PVOID ftHandle
          );
      ULONG WINAPI FT_EE_Read(
          PVOID ftHandle,
          PFT_PROGRAM_DATA pData
          );
      ULONG FT_EE_Program(
          PVOID ftHandle,
          PFT_PROGRAM_DATA pData
       );
      """
      )
      if other:
         self.ftd2xx = other.ftd2xx
         self.handle = other.handle
         self.data = other.data
      else: 
         self.ftd2xx = self.ffi.dlopen("ftd2xx.dll")
         pi = self.ffi.new("ULONG *")
         self.ftd2xx.FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(pi)
         assert pi[0] == 1, "exactly one device must hang on the PC, found "+str(pi[0])
         self.handle = self.ffi.new("PVOID *")
         self.ftd2xx.FT_Open(0,self.handle)
         assert self.handle[0]!=self.ffi.NULL, "could not open gEstim Device"
         self.data = self.ffi.new("PFT_PROGRAM_DATA");
         self.init_strings()
         self.errors = { 0:'FT_OK',
                   1:'FT_INVALID_HANDLE',
                   2:'FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND',
                   3:'FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED',
                   4:'FT_IO_ERROR',
                   5:'FT_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES',
                   6:'FT_INVALID_PARAMETER',
                   7:'FT_INVALID_BAUD_RATE'}
         err = self.ftd2xx.FT_EE_Read(self.handle[0],self.data)
         if err != 0:
            print("FT_EE_Read error ", self.errors[err])
   def init_strings(self,Manufacturer="",ManufacturerId="",Description="",SerialNumber=""):
         self._Manufacturer = self.ffi.new("char[64]",Manufacturer.encode())
         self._ManufacturerId = self.ffi.new("char [16]",ManufacturerId.encode())
         self._Description = self.ffi.new("char[64]",Description.encode())
         self._SerialNumber = self.ffi.new("char[16]",SerialNumber.encode())
         self.data[0].Manufacturer   = self.ffi.cast("void*",self._Manufacturer)
         self.data[0].ManufacturerId = self.ffi.cast("void*",self._ManufacturerId)
         self.data[0].Description    = self.ffi.cast("void*",self._Description)
         self.data[0].SerialNumber   = self.ffi.cast("void*",self._SerialNumber)
   def program(self):
      self.data[0].Signature1 = 0x00000000 
      self.data[0].Signature2 = 0xffffffff
      self.data[0].Version = 5
      self.data[0].VendorId   = self.VendorId
      self.data[0].ProductId  = self.ProductId
      self.init_strings( self.Manufacturer, self.ManufacturerId, self.Description, self.SerialNumber)
      err = self.ftd2xx.FT_EE_Program(self.handle[0],self.data)
      if err != 0:
         print("FT_EE_Program error ", self.errors[err])
   def __getattr__(self, item):
      if item in self.__dict__:
          return self.__dict__[item] 
      else:
          try:
             res = self.ffi.string(getattr(self.data[0],item)).decode()
             return res
          except TypeError:
             res = getattr(self.data[0],item)
             return res
   def close(self):
      self.ftd2xx.FT_Close(self.handle[0])
```